# Folders not available on a remote connection to a GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up my project on a Google Cloud Engine and want to be able to connect remotely to work on it in my local environment, but although I can successfully connect I can't access folders that I know to be in this location: /home/edjones378

I looks like I'm in the same place from checking the following:

Command in cloud shell terminal:

```
edjones378@cloudshell:~ (sound-oasis-363420)$ pwd
/home/edjones378
```

Command in local terminal connected with SSH:

```
edjones319@pitchtunabackend:~$ pwd
/home/edjones378
```

But when I create a test folder via the remote connection in my terminal, I can't see that in the cloud shell terminal and same thing for the other way.

Opening new shell sessions didn't work. This ssh key that I'm using was added to the metadata for the project so I think all instances should inherit it. I can't really see how there would be a permissions issue I should be viewing it as the same user.

Comment: Can you check whether you have permission to access files. Check if you have 

[Compute Engine viewer role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access#:~:text=Compute%20Engine%20viewer%20role) to view the files in gce.

Comment: Did you check the above comment? It helped you to resolve your issue? if not I am happy to assist further